# Jquery - Cannot post form that contains live data appended using jquery

Tags: internet-explorer-7, jquery

I have a form that I use to post Live data that is appended to the form using Jquery. The data that is appended contains an input box containing the value of the data I want the form to post. Everything works in Chrome, Firefox and IE8 but not IE7.

Why can't IE7 post live data. What am I doing wrong is there anyway to get around this???

See code below:

```
 <!--Start Cartbox-->
    <form method="get" name="register" action="process.php"> 

      <div id="cart" class="ui-widget-content ui-state-default">
        <h4 class="ui-widget-header"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-cart">Your Devices</span> Your Products</h4>
        <ul id="cartbox" class="cart ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix">

<!--EXAMPLE OF LIVE DATA-->

         <li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-tr">
              <h5 class="ui-widget-header">product 1</h5>
              <img src="product1.png"  alt="product1"/>

              <input type="hidden" name="devicetype[]" value="product1" />

              <div class="draggableicons"> 
<a style="float:left" href="#" title="<b>Product 1 ($150.00)</b><br />" class="vtip ui-icon ui-icon-info">More info...</a> 
<a href="#" title="<b>Add this product to cart</b>" class="vtip ui-icon ui-icon-cart">Add to cart</a> 
</div>
            </li>

<!--EXAMPLE OF LIVE DATA-->

        </ul>
      </div> 
    <button class="addbutton">Add the product to your cart</button>

  </form> 
<!--End Cartbox-->
```

Comment: Try removing the tooltips from the anchors, as they're invalid and may be casing the issue, see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an ending `</form>` tag

I also dont think jQuery plays well with '[]' in field or id/class names